# React Loadable Problem In My React Website

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me with the Issue in my React Website?

We have used react-loadable for chunks whenever we deploy it on production environment the website get stuck on the loading part. Below is the URL

URL WITH LOADABLE: http://fcastage.surge.sh/

Any help will be appreciated.

We have tried making the website using react loadabale and without react loadable. But to make the website fast and load in chunks we have to use loadable . The react loadable is working fine with Development Environment but its not working when I am switching to Production.

Below is the Config File for Production

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
//const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { ReactLoadablePlugin } = require('react-loadable/webpack')


const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build"),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
  },


  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              //because remove style-loader,my css can't work
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: "[local]"
              } // translates CSS into CommonJS
            },
            {
              loader: "less-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "assets/",
              limit: 10 * 1024
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              outputPath: "assets/"
            }
          }
        ]
      }  


    ]
  },
  optimization : {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10
        }
      }
    }
    // minimizer: [
    //   new UglifyJsPlugin({
    //     uglifyOptions: {
    //       compress: {
    //         unused: true,
    //         dead_code: true,
    //         warnings: false
    //       }
    //     },
    //     sourceMap: true
    //   }),
    // ]

  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./app/index.html",
      hash: true,
      filename: "index.html"
    }),
    //for surge.sh
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./app/index.html",
      hash: true,
      filename: "200.html"
    }),

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css"),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin( {'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    'process.env.DEBUG': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG) } ),

    new ReactLoadablePlugin({
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/react-loadable.json")
    })
  ],
};
```

Comment: Is there any warning printed out when you create the production build?